# How can I make a WordPress sub-menu with a top-level that isn't clickable?

Tags: menus

My WordPress website has a "Social Media" menu.
[image: Screenshot of billpg.com]

When using a touchscreen, when you tap the button, it takes you to a page. Only the little down-arrow next to it opens up the menu.

This is because the "Social Media" part is actually a link.
[image: Screenshot of menu admin]

How can I, using the WordPress administration panel, make this node of the menu just be the parent of a sub-menu? So if someone using a tablet taps the link it just opens the menu.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a Custom Links from Menus > Add menu items > Custom Links instead of a Wordpress page. your new custom link can be a parent of a sub-menu. Just drag it to the position required.

[image]